# Trying to create a calculated table based on Max() values of a drill through of an unrelated table Power BI

Tags: filter, powerbi, dax

In Power BI, I'm trying to use a measure to take the `= MAX(CallDetails[Date])` that is left once I drill through on a visual.

To create a calculated table. That is a filtered version of an unrelated table `AgentActivities` by `[Max Date]`.

My goal is to create 2 visuals side by side of the calls that came in on a select day with the agents that were available to take them.

I've tried quite a few vairants of this but this is essentially what i'm trying to do:

```
FilteredAgentActivity =
var MaxDate = [Max Date]
return
FILTER('AgentActivity',AgentActivity[Date] = MaxDate)
```

--This does not return any results

if I hard code the date I get the desired result:

```
FilteredAgentActivity =
FILTER('AgentActivity',AgentActivity[Date] = DATEVALUE("2020/04/18"))
```

At this point, I'm beginning to think using a measure as a filter expression might just not compatible with what I'm trying to achieve. Does anyone know where I'm going wrong or a better way of doing this?

Thanks
Ben

[Hard coding date works](https://i.stack.imgur.com/hMEsL.png)

[Measure variable fails](https://i.stack.imgur.com/vYbCp.png)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A calculated table *cannot* be dynamically dependent on report filtering since these are only computed when the data is initially loaded into your model (or when you refresh this data) but not whenever you change a filter.

Comment: Is there a way you can think of that it's achievable or do you think it's totally impossible?

Comment: That depends on what your ultimate goal is. If it's as narrow as creating a dynamic calculated table, then you are out of luck. However, it's very likely that you can solve the problem that you thought to use calculated tables for via a different method.

Comment: Thanks for your help Alexis.

Comment: If anyone else comes up against a similar issue. I was able to do this by:  
1. Creating a calculated column in both the tables with the merged values I was interested in.  

2. Then creating a many to many relationship between the two tables on that column in the direction I was trying to filter.